# Can ScreenUpdating=False still store operations?

Tags: excel, vba

I made a game in Excel/vba, and part of that game involves the activating of one random cell, then another, perhaps a hundred times. It's meant to be watched, but at times it won't be, and the ScreenUpdating will be turned off to make it run faster.

It's a multi-sheet game, and the sheet that does all the cell activating isn't accessed too often.  But, I find that if a long (processing) time has gone by, when I access that sheet it freezes up, and one could reasonably say it freezes the amount of time it would take to process those "hidden" cell activations.

So, here's the question: is it even possible that those processes that are done during ScreenUpdating=false are somehow "stored" in that sheet and need to be parsed once SU is turned back on and the sheet is accessed again?  Or is it just that the sheet is bad, and the freeze time that seems to correlate with the un-updated time is just a coincidence?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ScreenUpdating=false` may interfere with certain actions like showing a `msgbox`.

You need to set `ScreenUpdating=true` back again for things like that to work.

It is not possible that those processes need to be parsed once SU is turned back on, it just hides what is happening from the user but it is processed.

Comment: I've never seen `ScreenUpdating` affect `MsgBox`. Furthermore, OP doesn't mention `MsgBox`, right?